# Sed. Blank a field in csv file that includes symbol

Tags: regex, csv, sed

I have a large .csv file that looks like this:

> ABC, 10, <10.0, 10.0, ABC
>   ABC, < 0.9, 10, 10.0, ABC

I need to remove the fields that contain "<". Sometimes it's just "<" and numbers, sometimes it contains spaces, and it can appear on any column. This is the output I'm looking for:

> ABC, 10, , 10.0, ABC
>   ABC, , 10, 10.0, ABC

The closest thing to a success I got was

```
    grep -oP '(?<=,)(<.*?)(?=,)' text.csv
```

printed

> <10.0
>   < 0.9

which is what I want to delete. But

```
    sed -i 's/(?<=,)(<.*?)(?=,)/ /g' text.csv
```

does not work.
I ask for a *sed* solution because I'm a little familiar with it. But all suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/[^,]*<[^,]*//g' file
```

Using awk

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/</) $i=""}1' FS=, OFS=, file

ABC, 10,, 10.0, ABC
ABC,, 10, 10.0, ABC
```

Comment: +1 I like it when multiple suggestions are given, especially when OP is open for suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

this awk one-liner works, and more straightforward than sed.

```
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/</)$i=""}7' file
```

test

```
kent$  echo "ABC, 10, <10.0, 10.0, ABC
ABC, < 0.9, 10, 10.0, ABC"|awk -F, -v OFS="," '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~/</)$i=""}7'
ABC, 10,, 10.0, ABC
ABC,, 10, 10.0, ABC
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed as requested.

```
sed 's/[ ]*<[^,]*//g'
```

Comment: Since you have only one space between `[]` you can remove them, so this will work too: `sed 's/ *<[^,]*//g'`

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk '{gsub(/ ?< ?[^,]*/,x)}8' text.csv
ABC, 10,, 10.0, ABC
ABC,, 10, 10.0, ABC
```